# Suppose 5 fair dice are rolled and the total of the upmost faces noted.

Tags: combinatorics

What is the probability of obtaining 10 totals of 28 before 2 totals of 30?

My method so far has been to fix the number of throws = 12, assuming the last 2 are totals of 30, and then try to get the number of permutations of the preceding 10 throws, each of which is a 28 total. But the problem is each 28 may occur in 15 ways, so I don't how to progress. I'm grateful for any help...

Comment: What is the probability of throwing a $28$?  What is the probability of throwing a $30$? After you compute those, you'll want to it by states, keeping track of how many of each good sum you have seen.

Comment: Beginning with a clarification of the sample space- a very succinct explanation.

Answer (score 2):

*We shall consider only relevant rolls* (sum of $28$ or $30$),

so P(sum of $28$ in designated sample space) $= \frac{15}{16}$

To "win", either we must get $10$ straight rolls of sum $28$ or in $11$ rolls with one sum $30$ roll in the first $10$ rolls

Thus $Pr = \left(\frac{15}{16}\right)^{10} \left[ 1 + \binom{10}1\frac1{16}\right]$